# How to draw bounding contour on some points

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I have coordinates of some points,[image: for example this picture],

How can I draw a bounding curve on outer points?I mean I want to connect outer points,so inner point stay inside curve.
is there any easy way in `OpenCv` for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find convex hull:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html

Comment: But I think for convex hull you need to feed it with contours points and hierarchy,so it knows already,which points belong to outer contour,isn't it?But in my case they are not categorized by any hierarchy, they are just sporadic points saved in one `Mat` container

Comment: take a look at [convexhull.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/convexhull.cpp)

Comment: oh tank you very much this is what I need